# Highlight responses to a question from answerers who have a badge for one of the tags on the question

Tags: feature-request, answers, badges

Just an idea I had today for improving the site and identifying answers to your question that are more likely to be valid. The idea is that if the answering user has a badge for any of the tags that are present on the question, indicate it somehow on the answer.

Answer (score 8):

This sounds similar to the idea of following certain users, endorsing certain users, or marking certain users as trusted users. The problem that I see with such features is it creates a bit of an exponential effect on one's reputation score and can actually artificially inflate a post to make it seem more useful than it really is simply by association with a specific individual.

Since the content is the most important creation of Stack Exchange, it's critical that the content continue to stand on its own merits. Branding an answer based on a user being active in that tag may detract from that content.

In short, just because you've answered more Java questions than me doesn't mean that I can't contribute a valuable solution that is also the best solution.